# Knockout: Decoding html entities in an input field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-entities

I have a web app that allows users to submit and save HTML.  The user types in the html s/he wants to use into several different fields.  Some are text input elements and some are textarea elements.  When the user submits their markup I convert the special characters into html entities.

When the user comes back to edit the html they submitted I fetch their entries from the data base and prepopulate the form using knockout.  In order to display the html as they typed it, I call a function on any data that being bound to my view model to remove change any entities back into ampersands and brackets and all that fun stuff.

```
var viewModel = {
property : ko.observable(decode_entities(varContainingUserInput)),
....
}
```

I know when binding to most html elements like divs or p tags, you can use knockouts html binding to decode entities before you print them.  This alleviates the need to call the decode_entities function.  However this doesn't work with input fields.

I want to get rid of the decode_entities function, or roll it into knockout so it's not scattered all throughout my code.  I would like to get knockout to just decode entities in my bindings with any extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the observable (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)
take a look at the numeric extender in particular.

you can also use the custom binding, but i think that extending the observable will be a better solution for this case.